# Record .m4a file Android

Tags: android, audio-recording, m4a

How can i record M4A *audio* file with MediaRecorder in Android 2.2 ?
What output format, encoder and sampling rate i need to set ?

I need to record it from microphone and save it in SDCARD

**UPDATE**

I tried this code, but the result doesn't valid (not play in browser for example):

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); // error here ?!?
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000); // what value ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the bellow link

[how can i record audio file as .m4a format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357826/how-can-i-record-audio-file-as-m4a-format)

OR

http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/

this may help you.

Comment: I already set MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4. Second link is about 3GP format. Why if i try to read it from my browser (after export from sdcard) it doesn't work? Also VLC cant play it, while Android player work !!!

Answer (score 16):

These codes work to produce an m4a file:

```
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
```

or

```
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

with

```
    mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(absFilePath);// must have an .m4a extension
```

Comment: but for `ContentValues` you can only use `put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/aac")`, so it will create file with `.aac` extension instead of `.m4a`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change

`recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);`

to

```
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```